# nodeJS script can connect to aws mySQL server when run on laptop, but not when run on amazon EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the following script:

```
const pug = require('pug');
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var request = require('request');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var JSON = require('JSON');
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

var databaseConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'assignment3cloud.cfavdkskfrrc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 3306,
    user     : '<>',
    password : '<>',
    database : 'assign3'
});

databaseConnection  .connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ... \n\n");
    } else {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Error connecting database ... \n\n");
    }
});
```

When I run this script on my laptop, it runs A-OK.

When I run it on an amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance, I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT]
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
Error connecting database ... 


/home/ubuntu/home/skrpt.js:38
    if (error) throw error;
               ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:419:13)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:318:8)
    at _runOnTimeout (timers.js:524:11)
    at _makeTimerTimeout (timers.js:515:3)
    at Timer.unrefTimeout (timers.js:584:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/home/skrpt.js:27:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

My guess is that there is some additional security requirement in order to get the database to speak to the EC2 server. What can I do?

Comment: you need to add instance IP or its group in the security group of rds for incoming tcp request of port 3306

Comment: What are the security group settings for the RDS instance?

Comment: "Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances."

Sorry, I am not familiar with any of this.

Comment: I have set the security group to allow all traffic on port 3306 from any IP address, I am still having this problem. Both the EC2 instance and RDS instance are in this security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to add the MYSQL port in your inbound security rules for the instance (scroll horizontally to the right when you are on the page with your aws instances).

Comment: For the database instance or the EC2 instance?